# Using batch script to copy from file A and overwrite file B

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to take data from a .txt file and overwrite a .json file with this data. Typically I do this manually by copy-pasting but I was hoping to use a batch script to make this process quicker.

I have two iterations of this attempt.

**First iteration:**

```
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe D:\League\Config
COPY Tft.text >> PersistedSettings.json
```

This would give me an error message in my .json file `The system cannot find the file specified.`

So I went back to the drawing board and wound up with **Iteration 2:**

```
copy
D:\League\Config\Tft.text D:\League\Config\PersistedSettings.json
```

This seemingly does nothing and my.json file reverts to default. Before anyone asks, this is not illegal, I'm just modifying my configurations for a videogame.

All advice is appreciated thank you.

Comment: The last copy command cannot do nothing, it must either tell you it has copied successfully, or give an error that the file is in use?

Comment: Admittedly I am very new to programming. I have this batch script in the same folder of the .json file. I double click the script, file explorer blips and then I proceed to click on my .json file to see it has reverted to its default state. I have tested this by manually changing it and then running the batch script and it is indeed reverting.

Comment: ok, so at the end of your batch file, add `pause` then run it again, let me know what the output of the copy command is.

Comment: As you seem to be needlessly trying to use Windows Explorer, you should first of all understand that GUI processes have no part in this task. What you probably wanted was the `CD` command, `CD /D "D:\League\Config"`. Although, as you've told us that the batch file is in the same directory as the files, that would be better as `CD /D "%~dp0"`. You can find out more about these commands by using the standard help option `/?` too, perhaps with `CD /?` and `Call /?`. You could also use a similar single line method without changing directory, `Copy /Y "%~dp0Tft.text" "%~dp0PersistedSettings.json"`.

Comment: Thank you all so much for your input and your guidance! As a new programmer, I am prone to very silly mistakes. Taking what Mofi said into suggestion as well as changing my other txt files to.json I managed to make this script work. 

Once more, Thank you for your time and guidance.